# Bind a user control stack panel to an observable collection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a contact list user control with a stack panel bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `LoggedInUser`

User Control:

```
<UserControl.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Height="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" Grid.Column="0">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Height="30" Content="{Binding Username}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl.Content>
```

User Control Code Behind

```
public partial class ContactList : UserControl
{
    public ContactList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ContactListViewModel clvm = ContactListViewModel.GetInstance();

        clvm.Contacts.Add(new LoggedInUser("test", "123"));

        this.DataContext = clvm.Contacts;
    }
}
```

And my ContactListViewModel

```
class ContactListViewModel
{
    private static ContactListViewModel instance;

    public ObservableCollection<LoggedInUser> Contacts = new ObservableCollection<LoggedInUser>();

    public static ContactListViewModel GetInstance() 
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new ContactListViewModel();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

`LoggedInUser` class, just in case

```
public class LoggedInUser
{
    private string username;
    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }
}
```

My stack panel remains empty!  Help!

Comment: Are you using WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: I've only asked 6 questions and never got a satisfactory answer. Maybe this will be the one! Also, edited question to mention WPF.

Comment: You have not bound the ItemsControl's ItemsSource property to your viewModel's Contact property. Do this, and then instead of ` this.DataContext = clvm.Contacts;` write ` this.DataContext = clvm; `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not bound the `ItemsSource` of your `ItemsControl`, so it effectively has no data. Your data context is the collection, so you need only do this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...
```

Alternatively, if you instead set your data context to the view model instance (as is customary for MVVM), you would do this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" ...
```